# start postgresql server on linux system boot

Tags: linux, postgresql

I want to make the postgresql server on my linux machine to start automatically at system boot.
i added the following line in ~/.profile file:

```
su -c 'pg_ctl start -D /var/lib/pgsql/data ' postgres
```

however the postgres server doesn't start untill i lauch the console command . i'm then prompted to input password of user 'postgres' and then the server starts up correctly.

i want to avoid the two extar steps of lauching the linux console and entering the password for 'postgres' user. How can i do that?

Comment: normally these servers get started by a script in init.d, I am very surprised you need to do all this hoopla to start the server because if you install the postgres server package, your distro will somehow offer the possibility to autostart the server on start.  what distro do you use?  and how did you install postgresql?

Comment: @fvu: Great minds think alike! :)

Comment: @TomAnderson well yes, I am as surprised as you by the problems othman encounters...

Answer (score 3):

Here is an excerpt from the 8.0 manual that shows you how to do this with 8.* and for different distributions:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/postmaster-start.html

and here is for the most recent released version:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/server-start.html

> On Linux systems either add
>   `/usr/local/pgsql/bin/pg_ctl start -l logfile -D /usr/local/pgsql/data`
>   to `/etc/rc.d/rc.local` or `/etc/rc.local`
>   or look at the file
>   `contrib/start-scripts/linux` in the PostgreSQL source distribution.

Check paragraph starting with "Different systems have different conventions for starting up daemons at boot time."

Hope this helps.
Edmon

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you would do this with your system's initialisation framework. On traditional unixes, that means `/etc/init.d` scripts, but on modern ones, including the major Linux distributions, it is often something different.

Having said that, on modern unixes, installing PostgreSQL using the package manager will typically cause it to be launched on startup, so you shouldn't even need to do that.

What distribution of Linux are you using, and how have you installed PostgreSQL?

Comment: I use opensuse 12.1 and install postgresql from Yast repo. but i recently noticed the postgresql installation in opensuse 12.1 doesn't work out of the bow aand automatically configured. I had to configure by running initdb and some extra steps. I'm like you surprised why opensuse 12.1 no more install and configure postgresql automatically!

Comment: @othman are you sure you installed the `postgresql-server` package and used Yast to enable start on boot?  Haven't switched to 12.1 yet but in every OpenSuse version I ever used it worked flawlessly.

Comment: yes i'm sure i installed it via yast as i did usual. it uses to work well out of the box. but recently i reinstalled opensuse 12.1 after formatting my disc and when i installed postgresql from yast as usual i experience unusual problems in postgresql as it didn't get configured automatically and if i enable/start server from yast service run levels i get an error . that's why i decided to configure posstgresql manually. maybe something wrong in my freshly installed Opensuse 12.1 . I'm not sure what is the issue!

Comment: I have also seen systems (Fedora, IIRC) where installing PostgreSQL doesn't create a database, and you have to do that manually. But they do usually add an init.d hook. According to [this bug](https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=730326), if OpenSUSE isn't able to start PostgreSQL at boot, it just silently ignores it. Now you've created the database, perhaps it will start correctly at boot. Have you tried rebooting?